# How to use mix-blend-difference on a deeply nested child element without affecting other sibling elements?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am using both daisyUI with Tailwind for this project. I want to target a specific text here, in this case, the word 'developer':

[image: Screenshot of node element]

I want something similar to what is happening with shapes in [2015 XOXO festival webpage](https://2015.xoxofest.com/).

I've tried just using `mix-blend-difference`, but it does not work, probably because it is looking at the immediate parent element.

```html
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen" style="background-image: url(&quot;/src/images/mesh-gradient.png&quot;);">
   <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col base-100 text-base-content">
      <div class="hero bg-transparent h-96">
         <div class="hero-content text-center">
            <div class="max-w-md">
               <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold">
                  <div>Hi, I'm Anon,</div>
                  <div>a <span class="mix-blend-difference">developer</span></div>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Pretty sure that this is wrong, but I've also tried stacking multiple `mix-blend-difference`, starting from the immediate child to the nested element:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen" style="background-image: url(&quot;/src/images/mesh-gradient.png&quot;);">
   <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col base-100 text-base-content">
      <div class="hero bg-transparent h-96 mix-blend-difference">
         <div class="hero-content text-center mix-blend-difference">
            <div class="max-w-md mix-blend-difference">
               <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold mix-blend-difference">
                  <div class="mix-blend-normal">Hi, I'm Anon,</div>
                  <div class="mix-blend-difference"><span class="mix-blend-normal">a</span> <span class="mix-blend-difference">developer</span></div>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think 'stacking context' ([The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)). Each element that creates a new *stacking context* will discard the underlaying or parent element graphical settings. It looks like a 'new notepad with fresh pages' and new settings (in my head anyway, sorry!). Not using Tailwind. Check the MDN 'scenarios'.

Comment: Looks like daisyUI's `hero-content` had the property `z-index: 0`, which was messing up with the text. I had the choice to either remove the class, or add `z-auto`.

Comment: As long as you got the result you needed. At least you now know (hopefully) that *stacking context* has to be taken into account...

Comment: @RenevanderLende That is something new I've learnt for CSS. Looks like I'll have to go through the rules again sometimes later.

Comment: Yes, and then some. Happy ... hunting?!?

Answer (score 0):

daisyUI's `hero-content` is the culprit here.

```css
.hero-content {
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 80rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

It sets `z-index` to `0`, which causes `mix-blend-difference` to behave improperly. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Remove the class `hero-content`.
2. Add the class `z-auto` to override `hero-content` default `z-index` value.